# WordPress featured image embedded into a Bootstrap card container

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am using WordPress, Jetpack Photon, and Bootstrap 4. Here is my image tag that works but can’t be good practice....

```
 <?php echo '<img class="card-img img-fluid" src=' . the_post_thumbnail(array(375,300)) . '>'; ?>
```

I am trying to request the featured image with the_post_thumbnail(). I can’t get Photon to supply a scaled image that fits the width of my Bootstrap card container. The provided image is either a bit too slim or it overflows my card width. How can I get a Photon image to fit perfectly/responsively (width-wise)?

the_post_thumbnail(‘medium').... results in too small of an image for the card container.

the_post_thumbnail('large').... results in too large of an image and over flows it's card container.

Using Bootstrap’s max-width: 100% doesn’t seem to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of image tag, try:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class'=>'card-img img-fluid' ) ); ?>
```

The above function actually generate `<img class="card-img img-fluid" src="http://img-src">`

Comment: The above code seems to have the featured image placed (100% width) in my Bootstrap card container.

Comment: Can't help without any src or visual example.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your **functions.php** file to define new image size.

```
add_image_size( 'name-of-size', 375, 300, true );
```

to know more about add image size [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Add_New_Post_Thumbnail_Sizes).

**in the above line of code the name-of-size can be any unique name to represent the particular image size. The concept is while you upload any image to WordPress media it will crop to all image size defined and stored in wp-uploads folder.

***Also note that you will need to regenerate thumbnails for those images which were previously uploaded, if you need them in the new size.

Add the following code to your file to display image

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'name-of-size', array( 'class'=>'card-img img-fluid' ) ); ?>
```

Hope this is helpful, Thank you

Comment: I didn’t want to regenerate thumbnails, as I want the Bootstrap card image to be reflective of the card’s width and device view port. Photon seems to be providing an optimized version of my featured image and the 'img-fluid' attribute    seems to be filling the image entirely across the card's width. Here is the Photon image URL: src=“......Coquihalla_Summit_2076-2.jpg?fit=300%2C225&amp;ssl=1”. Am I correct here?

Comment: Dear Gordon then you have to do it with css. don't understand the url. you need custom code other than **the_post_thumbnail** function..? In custom code we will get particular url og the image and its properties in array.. then we can write image tag as we need. Is that your requirement..?

Comment: Manu.... I really wanted to just use the the_post_thumbnail function in conjunction with Jetpack Photon, having Photon provided the correct image size for my Bootstrap card width. Ahmad’s suggestion seems to make this happen.